# Unrecognized Content-Security-Policy directive 'script-src:'

Tags: content-security-policy, crosswalk

in my ionic application I've added crosswalk to get a better android performance. But if I run the application I get this error:

```
Unrecognized Content-Security-Policy directive 'script-src:'.
```

My Content-Security-Policy looks like this:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src: 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">
```

Why is this Content-Security-Policy throwing an error?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It should be:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">
```

The `:` value does not belong anywhere in a policy as a delimiter.